# Authentication error of Google Earth Engine QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have updated my QGIS to version  `3.28.3-Firenze`. I already installed the `Google Earth Engine` QGIS Plugin. After the update the plugin doesn't work. It asks for GCloud. I also installed that but not sure how to fix it.

1. In QGIS python terminal when I type 
   import ee 
   ee.Authenticate()
   The following error shows.
   [image: Error]

**Exception: gcloud failed. Please check for any errors above and install gcloud if needed.**

How do I fix this?

I have seen a lot of relevant posts to earth engine authentication but they're not helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download GCloud For Windows : https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe
   or pip install gcloud (if you are using cmd/terminal/powershell)
2. Once the installation is complete, restart the computer and run the **google cloud sdk shell**
3. Type **pip install earthengine-api** and press enter
4. Then type **python** and press enter
5. Type **import ee** and press enter
6. Type **ee.Authenticate()** and press enter, it will load browser with the authentication link. Login and verify your account.
7. Type **ee.Initialize()**
   Done you can now call GEE API from cmd, QGIS, or any terminal

Email if the issue persists: muddasirshah@outlook.com

Comment: You don't need to authenticate every time. Authentication is one time. Once your account is authenticated just import ee and ee.Initialize()